# Chat con socket.io emita un pitido en los otros usuarios

Tags: nodejs, socket.io

Tengo un chat son node.js y socket.io funcionando, y cuando se envia un mensaje se emite un pitido para que los usuarios conectados sepan que tienen un mensaje. El problema es que el pitido suena tanto en el que envia el mensaje como el que lo recibe. Yo solo quiero que suene en el que lo reciba.

En el cliente tengo esto

```
var mySound = new Audio('/chatear/sonido.mp3');
mySound.load();

socket.on('message', message => {
  console.log(message);
  outputMessage(message);

  // Scroll down
  chatMessages.scrollTop = chatMessages.scrollHeight;

  mySound.play();
});
```

Funciona bien pero suena en los dos lados.

El servidor emite esto:

```
socket.on('chatMessage', msg => {
    const user = getCurrentUser(socket.id);
    
    io.to(user.room).emit('message', formatMessage(user.username, msg));       
    //io.to(user.username).emit('message', formatMessage(user.username, mensa));
    var hoy=new Date();
    fecha=hoy.getFullYear()+'-'+(hoy.getMonth()+1)+'-'+hoy.getDate();
    hora=hoy.getHours()+':'+hoy.getMinutes()+':'+hoy.getSeconds();
    db.query("INSERT INTO chat_mensajes (id_usuario,id_fecha,id_hora,id_room,id_mensaje) VALUES (' " + user.username + " ','"+fecha+"','"+hora+"','"+user.room+"','"+msg+"')");

  });
```

La instrucción :

io.to(user.room).emit('message', formatMessage(user.username, msg));

Envia el mensaje a todos, si la cambio por

io.to(user.username).emit('message', formatMessage(user.username, mensa));

Yo creia que solo la enviaria a un usuario y así no envia el mensaje.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Un pitido a un usuario particular o a toda una sala? ¿Cuál es el resultado final que deseeas? Saludos

Comment: Como resultado final quería sólo a un usuario. De momento sólo entran dos usuarios.